# Is WiFi Display Sink source code migrated into Google Cast?

Tags: android-source, google-cast

This is about AOSP and maybe Google Cast. I posted this question to Google group android-platform for several days, but no answer.

In AOSP git log, it says obsolete miracast sink code and friends are removed as below commit, from frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/wifi-display/.

```
commit 6ea551fa13b69e5ce359a7dba7485d857a005304
Author: Andreas Huber <andih@google.com>
Date:   Wed Oct 2 13:06:06 2013 -0700

Remove obsolete miracast sink code and friends.

Change-Id: I8bbb22fb0cfe2d73881d9f05bf8112ae86d8040b
related-to-bug: 11047222
```

Would anyone point to me where is the latest WiFi Display Sink source code? Is it integrated into Google Cast? Thanks.

xuebing wang

Comment: Why don't you ask Andreas Huber? Seems you have his contact details.

Comment: I used to send an email to google engineer once, but no reply. I presume it's not easy for google engineers to maintain android development velocity (with this many features coming out), I try not bothering them too much. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

> Would anyone point to me where is the latest WiFi Display Sink source
>   code?

[WiFi Display Sink source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/android-sdk-support_r11/media/libstagefright/wifi-display/sink/WifiDisplaySink.cpp)

[Miracast Source Code by Kensuke](https://github.com/kensuke/How-to-Miracast-on-AOSP/wiki/Android-4.4)

> Is it integrated into Google Cast?

There is no mention that Googled used miracast in Cast although there are similarities.
"[Miracast](http://www.howtogeek.com/200796/what-is-miracast-and-why-should-i-care/) is a wireless display standard designed for mirroring a smartphone, tablet, or PC’s screen to a television without requiring any physical HDMI cables". This [mirroring feature](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/remote) is just one of the many things Chrome Cast can do. More on [Google Cast](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/developers) here.

Comment: Thanks. I'd think the protocols underneath Google Cast are WiFi Display (aka Miracast) and Apple Airplay. I actually noticed Kensuke's question "Sink implementation Source Code Deleted Again! Hi, Mr.Huber, WHY ARE YOU DELETING SINK SOURCE CODE BEFORE AOSP RELEASE?" I am less interested in why Mr. Huber deleted the obsolete source code, I am more interested in where is the latest (not obsolete) WiFi Direct sink source code. Possibly Google integrated it into Google Cast, and make it close-source??

Comment: Remote Display and Mirroring in Google Cast SDK is not based on Miracast.

Comment: There is no mention in the Google Docs that Cast uses miracast. However, I think Cast can provide the service you're trying to do with Miracast like mirroring.

Comment: Thanks. I think you are correct, Google Cast is not based on Miracast. A little google shows that it seems it is based on DIAL protocol, like "One of Chromecast's components, the DIAL Service Discovery protocol, uses Simple Service Discovery Protocol (SSDP) version 1.1, which is defined by UPnP (Universal Plug and Play), to allow a DIAL client device to locate a DIAL server device running on the same network. The other component, the DIAL REST (Representational State Transfer) Service ..."

Comment: However, I still have no idea where is latest Miracast sink source code after Mr. Huber deleted it on Oct 2 2013 (I have not carefully checked it, possibly before Android 4.4.4 release).